# Copying only certain values from a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with the following data. I want to set up a rule that pastes the values in the first two columns to a separate table when the third column is True.

```
1   1   0   False
1   1.2 0   False
1   1.4 0   False
1   1.6 0   False
1   1.8 0   False
1   2   0   False
1   2.2 0   False
1   2.4 0   False
1   2.6 0   False
1   2.8 0   False
2   1   0   False
2   1.2 0   False
2   1.4 0   False
2   1.6 0   False
2   1.8 0   False
2   2   0   False
2   2.2 33.5 False
2   2.4 79.8 False
2   2.6 100 PASSED
2   2.8 100 PASSED
```

desired output:

```
                        new table with values that have 'TRUE' 
1   1   0   False       2   2.6
1   1.2 0   False       2   2.8
1   1.4 0   False       
1   1.6 0   False       
1   1.8 0   False       
1   2   0   False       
1   2.2 0   False       
1   2.4 0   False       
1   2.6 0   False       
1   2.8 0   False       
2   1   0   False       
2   1.2 0   False       
2   1.4 0   False       
2   1.6 0   False       
2   1.8 0   False       
2   2   0   False       
2   2.2 33.5 False      
2   2.4 79.8 False      
2   2.6 100 PASSED      
2   2.8 100 PASSED
```

Is this possible in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this - the simplest is to simply filter on the 'TRUE/FALSE' column, showing only TRUE values. Then copy & paste to a new sheet. OR, take your data table, and create a pivot which filters for TRUE values.

For a slightly more dynamic approach which updates without manual intervention, you could do the following:

Add a new column to the right of your current data table. Starting at D2 and scrolling down [if you have headers, no further action is necessary. If you have no headers, hardcode D1 to be 1 if TRUE, 0 if FALSE], put the following:

```
=IF(C2,MAX($D$1:D1)+1,"")
```

The D column will now iterate up by 1, each time there is a row in column C which says TRUE.

Now, on your other sheet, you can create an index (1, 2, 3, etc.) on column A. Beside that index, you put the following on B2 [assuming headers exist on row 1] and copy down and to the right [This assumes your original table is in Sheet1]:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!A:A,MATCH($A1, 'Sheet1'!$D:$D,0))
```

This pulls in the value from the appropriate column [note: no $'s referencing Sheet1's column A - this means it will move to the right as you move your formula to the right], wherever it matches the same index number in column A, as you have in Sheet1's column D.

Comment: Nice and no array formulas.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have managed to get the index in the iteration of column D, however cannot seem to work out the next bit with the indexing? Why do I need to create another index on a separate sheet. Can this not be done on the same sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$20,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$20)/($D$1:$D$20="PASSED"),ROW(1:1)))
```

Put in the first cell and copy right and down.

The Aggregate formula was introduced in 2010.  It will not work in earlier versions.

For earlier versions you will need to use this Array formula:

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$20,SMALL(IF($D$1:$D$20="PASSED",ROW($1:$20)),ROW(1:1)))
```

As it is an Array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving Edit mode.  Then it too can be copied over and down.

[image]